# Why cant I update my Gta 5 and access online?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I own a PS3super slim. I was updating my GTA 5 and while doing so the PS3 was accidentally shut down. This happened while the screen displayed update no. 14/20 (as in 6 more updates were pending).

Now as it happens with other games, the option to update your game should come as soon as the game is launched, and yet nothing of the sort happens when I launch my GTA 5. When I access online it says

> Success, a new content was downloaded and installed. Please return to Gta 5.

And with this, it takes me back to offline mode. Please guide with proper steps about what I should do.